# Бинарное дерево

Tags: алгоритм, c, бинарное-дерево, c++

Помогите правильно вставить предка в каждую структуру.
http://codepad.org/Ynjz6G3L
В функции add_tree и create_tree.

Comment: что то до меня так и не доходит, а что должно происходить, это же вы про 104 строку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Делов-то! `head->left->predok=head;` и соответственно `head->right->predok=head;`. Ну и конечно `phead->predok=NULL;`.

И кстати, не `predok`, а `parent`.

Вы бы лучше порисовали квадратики со стрелочками, задача элементарная.

Comment: http://codepad.org/h0sQp9dX
Я правильно понял? Если да, то у меня не работает.

Comment: @stupidmonkey: Ну да, правильно. А что значит «не работает»? Код правильный.

Comment: По идее в maine в этой строке cout << search(phead, key) -> predok -> key << endl; сначала нахожу по ключу, потом у этого ключа вывожу предка. Но прога вылетает.
http://cs622823.vk.me/v622823450/330d/8jPtDCZr3-I.jpg

Comment: @stupidmonkey: Ну да, ваш прокол. У корня-то предка нет. А находит функция, небось, корень.

Comment: search? 
не, она находит ключ, который задается в аргументе и возвращает указатель на него, phead - указатель на корень, соответственно. 
На скрине видно, что корень 5, ключ я задаю 6, он мне находит ключ, возвращает на него указатель, я пытаюсь обратиться к predok этого указателя, и оно вылетает.

Comment: @stupidmonkey: дайте полную программу, а? чтобы вводило не с консоли, а закодировано в коде.

Comment: Для 15,18,20 действительно находится предок, но для остальных почему то вылетает
http://codepad.org/QXXdy8O5

Comment: @stupidmonkey: Вот ваш код:

    search(temp->left, key);

А что происходит с возвращённым из `search` значением? (Подсказка: _ничего, оно тупо игнорируется_.)